# Исполняемый файл python после pyinstaller не закрывается автоматически (SELENIUM)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-3.7

Программу пробовал паковать как через cxfreeze так и через pyinstaller.

Ни там ни там, программа автоматически не закрывается, т.е окно остаётся открытым.

пробовал:

```
sys.exit()
os.abort()
os._exit(0)
raise SystemExit
```

[image: проблема]

На скрине видно что скрипт закончил работу, в исходнике на данный момент есть `sys.exit(0)`

Программу могу завершить, лишь нажав на крестик, либо зажав `ctrl - c`

Есть у кого идеи, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: sys.exit()* Так же, хочу добавить что в ide программа закрывается спокойно, после sys.exit()

Comment: добавьте код. или хотя бы прототипы функций и объяснения что они делают.

Comment: Для начала проверьте как отрабатывает pyinstaller на более простом коде. Например:
```import os
os.system("pause") # чтобы увидеть что программа отработала
os._exit(0)
```
Проверьте на всякий случай что у вас отключено создание консольного окна `pyinstaller -w script.py`. Хотя для приведенного выше примера это не играет роли.
Программа закрывается если ее запустить как скрипт без ide?

Comment: @Kers, Программа закрывается если запустить её просто через cmd.. Попробовал собрать с ключом -w заметил что открывается cmd окно chromedriver.exe. На элементарном коде программа без проблем закрывается.. В своём коде я использую selenium, драйвер его я заблаговременно закрываю, и он вроде бы закрывается. Но само окно скрипта - нет...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблему решил. Всё дело было в не закрывающемся драйвере selenium..

Дело в том что  `driver.close()` не закрывает chromedriver.exe полностью, а закрывает только окно браузера. Мне повезло и я нашёл `driver.__exit__()` он гасит chromedriver.exe и после этого `sys.exit()` спокойно отрабатывает и гасит скрипт.

Comment: Дай бог тебе здоровья. Спасибо.